# How to Rig a Character's Spine if the Face is Part of the Body?

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

So I am watching a course on rigging and most characters are human like with a normal spine and face is separated with their neck.

However, my character has it's face on the body. Here's an example

[image]

Is it necessary to include multiple bones for the spine or should I just use one giant bone?

Because they used a completely different face rig to do expressions, but I don't know how I would implement that if my spine is literally the face as well?

[image]

Also, if I want to make my character knod yes or no, is that possible to only using one bone? or would I need to create it like my image above then add loop cuts in the areas of my character where he would bend to knod his head up or down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of bones will completely depend on how you want your character to bend, if it is not supposed to bend on its middle, you don't need to create several bone, one will be enough. Also the topology will be important, the mesh will bend if it is able to. As for the face bones (eyes, eyebrows, mouth, etc), just parent them to the spine bone (or, if you have several bones, parent to the closest bone, top bone or middle bone...)

Comment: but regarding the facial rig and expressions, will that affect the layout since the facial bones would be overlapping the same area as the spine?

Comment: the bones for eyes, eyebrows, mouth, will be parented to the spine, but you still don't need to divide the spine.

Comment: @moonboots: i am so happy he doesn't need to divide the spine. This would be very cruel and i am happy you are so heart warming to save the spine!!!! ❤️

Comment: plus you save the price of several bones and I've heard they were much expensive